# Change RabbitMQ bindings

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have one application which acts as a publisher and regularly sends messages to an exchange and a dozen others (subscribers) which are groped semantically by topics. My problem is that the subscribers can move between different groups, hence their topic subscription should change, but I cannot figure out a way how to alter the bindings dynamically. Any ideas?

My config for each subscriber looks like this:

```
@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(exchangeName);
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingKey);
}

@Bean
Queue queue(SystemInformationService systemInformationService) {
    return new Queue(systemInformationService.getInfo().getTemplateName() != null ?  systemInformationService.getInfo().getTemplateName() : queueName , true);
}
```

}

P.S: I must not restart my Subscriber SpringBoot application, otherwise it is quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change bindings; you can, however, add and remove them.

You can either do that manually using the management UI or you can use a `RabbitAdmin`.